# mssql server - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I have problem with ELSE function

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @a AS int = 2;
DECLARE @b AS int = 4;
DECLARE @c AS int = 1;
DECLARE @delta AS int;
DECLARE @x0 AS int;
DECLARE @x1 AS int;
DECLARE @x2 AS int;

BEGIN
    SET @delta = POWER(@b, 2) - 4 * @a * @c
            IF @delta > 0
                SET @x1 = -@b - SQRT(@delta) / 2 * @a
                SET @x2 = -@b + SQRT(@delta) / 2 * @a
                PRINT 'Delta equals: ' + CAST(@delta AS varchar) + 'x1: ' + CAST(@x1 AS varchar) + 'x2: ' + CAST(@x2 AS varchar);
            ELSE IF @delta = 0
                SET @x0 = -@b / 2 * @a
                PRINT 'Delta equals: ' + CAST(@delta AS varchar) + 'x0: ' + CAST(@x0 AS varchar);
            ELSE
END
```

Errors I get:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
> 'ELSE'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 18 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
> 'ELSE'.

Comment: A statement should follow the `ELSE`.  This looks pretty obvious.

Comment: You need to use `BEGIN` and `END` a little more, too. `IF` and `ELSE` statements only affect the immediately following statement unless you use a `BEGIN ... END` block, e.g.: `IF ... BEGIN ... END ELSE BEGIN ... END`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly have a dangling `ELSE` clause and are missing `BEGIN`/`END`.

However, I want to caution you against using `varchar` (or *any* string declaration) in SQL Server without a length.  The length varies by context and leaving out the length is often a bug just waiting to happen.

The simplest solution is to use `CONCAT()`:

```
BEGIN
    SET @delta = POWER(@b, 2) - 4 * @a * @c;
    IF @delta > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @x1 = -@b - SQRT(@delta) / 2 * @a;
        SET @x2 = -@b + SQRT(@delta) / 2 * @a;
        PRINT CONCAT('Delta equals: ', @delta, 'x1: ', @x1, 'x2: ', @x2);
    END;
    ELSE IF @delta = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @x0 = -@b / 2 * @a;
        PRINT CONCAT('Delta equals: ', @delta, 'x0: ', @x0);
    END;
END;
```

`CONCAT()` automatically converts values to strings for the concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an empty `ELSE`, and if you have multiple statements you need to use `BEGIN`/`END`:

```
IF @delta > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @x1 = -@b - SQRT(@delta) / 2 * @a
        SET @x2 = -@b + SQRT(@delta) / 2 * @a
        PRINT 'Delta equals: ' + CAST(@delta AS varchar) + 'x1: ' + CAST(@x1 AS varchar) + 'x2: ' + CAST(@x2 AS varchar);
    END
ELSE IF @delta = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @x0 = -@b / 2 * @a
        PRINT 'Delta equals: ' + CAST(@delta AS varchar) + 'x0: ' + CAST(@x0 AS varchar);
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax you want is:

```
DECLARE @a AS int = 2;
DECLARE @b AS int = 4;
DECLARE @c AS int = 1;
DECLARE @delta AS int;
DECLARE @x0 AS int;
DECLARE @x1 AS int;
DECLARE @x2 AS int;


SET @delta = POWER(@b, 2) - 4 * @a * @c;
IF @delta > 0
BEGIN
    SET @x1 = -@b - SQRT(@delta) / 2 * @a;
    SET @x2 = -@b + SQRT(@delta) / 2 * @a;
    PRINT 'Delta equals: ' + CAST(@delta AS varchar) + 'x1: ' + CAST(@x1 AS varchar) + 'x2: ' + CAST(@x2 AS varchar);
END
ELSE IF @delta = 0
BEGIN
    SET @x0 = -@b / 2 * @a;
    PRINT 'Delta equals: ' + CAST(@delta AS varchar) + 'x0: ' + CAST(@x0 AS varchar);
END
```

Rationale:

- the trailing `ELSE` needs to be removed
- blocks that contain multiple instructions need `BEGIN` and `END`
- the surrounding `BEGIN/END` are not necessary